# Reasons to not use the default exchange on RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I've started working with RabbitMQ and my use case is quite simple - producers putting messages on queues to to processed by consumers. Each message is processed by at most one consumer and messages are directed from producer to consumer based on queue name.

`Direct` exchanges seem perfectly fine for this and the `default` exchange is a `direct` exchange.

Are there any reasons (performance, management, permissioning etc.) to not use the `default` exchange and create your own one instead? For example, I will be using high-availability queues (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) and wasn't sure if there would be any negative impact on the cluster if all the HA queues were on the `default` exchange as opposed to a different exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default exchange you gain performance, since there's almost no routing logic involved, but then you end up coupling your publishers to your consumers, which is kinda an anti-pattern in messaging.

At the same time if your concern is performance, I doubt RabbitMQ's routing performance would be the first problem you encounter. Queue paging, queue synchronization over a network in the case of HA, and so on, seems like things I would worry about when caring for performance.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't worried about performance per se (it was just an example) but more if there are any good reasons to not use the default exchange if I want direct routing. For example, I recently found out that there are limitations around the default exchange and federation.

Comment: I don't see a reason to use the deafult exchange unless you are doing something like RPC